# LinkWithCredentials process help for creating single account for user

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am building an app that requires users to fill in the details for the sign-up screen.. once they fill in all the details and verification of details then I allow them to enter their email ID. once the email id is validated (1. blank email 2. invalid email id 3. existing email id check through Firebase) then the app will CREATE email for the user (using email password).. CREATION OF EMAIL has 3 phases.

- A. Email creation itself and
- B. Sending verification email to the user.
- C. Waiting until the user verifies the email.

upon verification of email, I am allowing the user to enter the mobile number. On filling the mobile validation of it will happen (1. blank mobile 2. invalid mobile No 3. existing mobile check through Firebase). if validation turns positive I am asking them to verify the mobile through OTP (new activity). after OTP verification, Finally, I am storing all the user's data into firebase (except the password).

My actual problem lies here. I want users to log in through the phone OTP process or email password process. currently, I am unable to link the email and phone of the user as firebase is considering as 2 accounts. on google, I came to know that I had to link using the `LinkWithCredential` option. however, it's not working...

Here is my `VerifyOTP` codes where phone authentication happening...

```java
public class VerifyOTP extends AppCompatActivity {
@BindView(R.id.PinViewUser)
PinView PinViewUser;
@BindView(R.id.btnVerify)
Button btnVerify;
@BindView(R.id.btnGetOTP)
Button btnGetOTP;
@BindView(R.id.btnResend)
Button btnResend;
@BindView(R.id.txtCodeVerificationText)
TextView txtCodeVerificationText;
@BindView(R.id.Verificationlabel)
TextView Verificationlabel;
@BindView(R.id.txtNoteToUser)
TextView txtNoteToUser;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
AuthCredential emailCredential;
String  UserPhoneNo, CodeBySystem, PhNoThroughSignUp, PhNoThroughForgotPassword, ForwardEmailToNextClass, GetCredEmail, GetCredPass;
PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
private static final String TAG = "AnonymousAuth";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    RunAppOnFullScreenMode();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify_o_t_p);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    //get Ph No & Other Details from SignupLayout
    PhNoThroughSignUp = getIntent().getStringExtra(ReUsuableCode.CustomMobileNo);
    GetCredEmail = getIntent().getStringExtra("CredEmail");
    GetCredPass = getIntent().getStringExtra("CredPass");

    emailCredential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(GetCredEmail, GetCredPass);
    //get Ph No from ForgotPassword
    PhNoThroughForgotPassword = getIntent().getStringExtra("FPMobile");

    if (PhNoThroughSignUp == null) {
        UserPhoneNo = PhNoThroughForgotPassword;
    } else {
        UserPhoneNo = PhNoThroughSignUp;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Email: " + GetCredEmail + "Password: " + GetCredPass + "Phone: " + UserPhoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// this is working
    txtCodeVerificationText.setText("Click On Get OTP Button to Get the OTP on the Mentioned Phone No\n\n Note: Standard SMS charges May Apply");
    Log.d(TAG, "DetailsCollected");
    // Initialize Firebase Auth
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //Send OTPCode to User
    btnGetOTP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SendVerificationCodeToUser(UserPhoneNo);
            Log.d(TAG, "Verification Code Sent");
            txtNoteToUser.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtCodeVerificationText.setText("Enter the One Time Password received on\n " + UserPhoneNo);
            Toast.makeText(VerifyOTP.this, "OTP Initiated!! Wait For Auto Verification of OTP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    btnVerify.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }, 10000); // where 1000 is equal to 1 sec (1 * 1000)
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    btnResend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }, 60000); // where 1000 is equal to 1 sec (1 * 1000)
        }
    });

    //ReSend OTPCode to User
    btnResend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            resendVerificationCode(UserPhoneNo, mResendToken);
            txtCodeVerificationText.setText("Resent verification code to " + UserPhoneNo + "\n\n Note: Standard SMS charges May Apply");
            btnResend.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    btnResend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }, 60000); // where 1000 is equal to 1 sec (1 * 1000)
        }
    });

    //Manual Click on VerifyButton
    btnVerify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String code = PinViewUser.getText().toString();
            if (ReUsuableCode.fieldisEmpty(code)) {
                PinViewUser.setError("Field is Empty");
            } else {
                VerifyCode(CodeBySystem, code);
            }
        }
    });

}

//======================================= Other Private Codes==================
private void SendVerificationCodeToUser(String phNo) {
    PhoneAuthOptions options =
            PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                    .setPhoneNumber(phNo)       // Phone number to verify
                    .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                    .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                    .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                    .build();
    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
}


public void linkCredential(AuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "linkWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        Toast.makeText(VerifyOTP.this, "linkWithCredential:success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (PhNoThroughSignUp == null) {
                            Intent GoToAnotherLayout1 = new Intent(VerifyOTP.this, SetPassword.class);
                            ForwardEmailToNextClass = getIntent().getStringExtra("FEmail");
                            GoToAnotherLayout1.putExtra("FEmail", ForwardEmailToNextClass);
                            startActivity(GoToAnotherLayout1);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            Intent GoToAnotherLayout1 = new Intent(VerifyOTP.this, Retailer_SignUP.class);
                            GoToAnotherLayout1.putExtra(ReUsuableCode.MobileRegistration, "Mobile Validation Successful");
                            setResult(RESULT_OK, GoToAnotherLayout1);
                            finish();
                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "linkWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(VerifyOTP.this, "linkWithCredential:failure" + task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}

private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks =
        new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
        // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
        CodeBySystem = s;
        mResendToken = forceResendingToken;
        Log.d(TAG, "OnCode Completed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        Log.d(TAG, "On Verification start");
        Toast.makeText(VerifyOTP.this, "OTP Verification Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
        if (code != null) {
            PinViewUser.setText(code);
            VerifyCode(CodeBySystem, code);
            Log.d(TAG, "Pre Link State");
            linkCredential(emailCredential);
            Log.d(TAG, "Post Link State");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Verification Failed");
        if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
            Toast.makeText(VerifyOTP.this, "Failed to Verify!! Try After Some Time...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
            Toast.makeText(VerifyOTP.this, "Too Many Attempts!! Try After Some Time...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(VerifyOTP.this, "Some Other Error Occured...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }
};

private void VerifyCode(String verificationId, String code) {
    PhoneAuthCredential Credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
    Log.d(TAG, "Verified Code");
}


// [START resend_verification]
private void resendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber,
                                    PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
    PhoneAuthOptions options =
            PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                    .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)       // Phone number to verify
                    .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                    .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                    .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                    .setForceResendingToken(token)     // ForceResendingToken from callbacks
                    .build();
    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
}
```

here are my error logs: 
[image]

Please do guide me where I am missing. How to do I make a single account for the user?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get an answer to my code. Here is the website which I referred to fix the code: [Learning Path for Linking Phone and Email](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Linking_and_Unlinking_Firebase_Authentication_Providers)

Steps to Link with 2nd Auth Provider of Firebase:

As per my scenario, I am first making the user enter an email ID and hence I make the user to first SIGN IN using email ID and password, which is nothing but,

1. Creation of Account with Email and Password
2. Sending Verification email (Optional step)
3. Waiting until User validates email ID (Optional Step)
4. Signing in the User using first Auth Provider (`EmailAuthProvider`).

After the signing process is complete. I made the user enter a mobile number so that he can proceed to validate the Ph No. In this follow the below process

1. Send a verification code to the user's phone
2. In the callbacks method of `onVerificationCompleted`. instead of regular signing-in with phAuth provider you have to use `Linkwithcredentials(phcredentials)`
   which is:

   a)

   ```
   PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
   ```

   b)

   ```
   linkCredential(PhCredential);
   ```
3. If you are using the manual verification of OTP then link the 2a and 2b step to `verifybtn` as well.

   ```
   public void linkCredential(AuthCredential credential) {
       mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
               .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                       if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                           Log.d(TAG, "linkWithCredential:success");


                       } else {
                           Log.w(TAG, "linkWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                           Toast.makeText(VerifyOTP.this, "linkWithCredential:failure" + task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   }
               });
   ```